# How to Change the HTTP Response Type in handleError Hook in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app with several `+page.server.ts` files calling a database. When the database code notices a mismatch between the action it is requested and the credentials it receives, it will throw an error of a particular type `class Forbidden extends Error`.

When such an error happens, and unless it is caught somewhere, I would like to return a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response. One solution would be to write `throw error(403, 'forbidden')` in a `catch` case in every such `+page.server.ts`, but I am looking for something I can write once and that would apply to every `+page.server.ts`.

One thing was thinking about is the `handleError` hook in `hooks.server.ts` because I do get to intercept every such error and I can do a `if (error instanceof Forbidden)`, however it seems that in `handleError` you can only change the content of the error and not the HTTP status code which will always be 500.

Now I'm thinking what I would need is a sort of hook that is always passed the output of every server `load` function so that I have an opportunity to turn it into a `throw error(403)` if needed, but I am not aware of any such hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [handle server hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle) for this. Take a look at this example:

```js
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    let response = await resolve(event);
    if (/* response needs a status change */) {
        response = new Response(response.body, { ...response, status: 403 });
    }

    return response;
}) satisfies Handle;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did consider this and it does make sense but I have no idea of an efficient mechanism to tell that a response needs a status change. I am definitely not going to parse the HTML in the response looking for a particular error message. I wish I could intercept a Javascript error and not an HTTP response which creation I don't control.

Comment: Ah! I understand you now. I was confused because you said that it always returned 500 so I thought you were looking for something like `if (response.status === 500) {`. If, this is what you want, just use an status code as signal (like 418 "I'm a teapot"). I have to admit it is a very rare situation to be honest. I would probably work in a different direction like making the `Forbidden` to extend `HttpError` with the correct status code or abstracting the database loading function to throw the right error straight away (i.e. work on your code before the error happens, not after).